# From Markdown to PDF: how to change the font-size with Pandoc?

Tags: pdf, latex, font-size, pandoc

I'm converting some Markdown files into PDF using Pandoc like this:

```
pandoc input.md -V geometry:margin=1in -o output.pdf
```

By default, the font-size is quite small in the pdf. I'd like to make all the fonts bigger (title, sub title, text, etc.). How can I do that?

Answer (score 54):

Add this to your incantation:

```
-V fontsize=12pt
```

Comment: I just tried "pandoc input.md -V fontsize=20pt -o output.pdf", and I don't see any difference in the fontsize of the pdf

Comment: The standard latex article document class doesn't support 20pt.  Try 12pt.

Comment: And if I want to increase the size to 14pt, how can I do that?

Comment: @pimpampoum as John wrote the "standard.." does not support it. But it should be possible to fully customize the output through the [pandoc templates](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/templates.html). Take a look at the GitHub template repository where you should be able to tweak anything you need at https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates

Comment: Yes, this might be useful:  http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes.  If you have this package installed, you can change your default latex template to use `extarticle` instead of `article`.  Then some larger font sizes will be available. See the pandoc README on customizing your latex template.

Comment: and how do i do that?

Answer (score 46):

If you want to go bigger than 12pt you can use the [extsizes package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes).
Was already pre installed for me, so this worked out of the box with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org):

```
---
documentclass: extarticle
fontsize: 14pt
---

…
```

Possible sizes are 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt.

Comment: This was the most convenient.  And you can also add other flags e.g. `pagestyle: empty` for no page-numbers.

Comment: does this work with pdflatex?

Comment: i can't get this or any of the other solutions to work on `macOS` where I have `basicLatex` installed

Answer (score 32):

For new users of pandoc (like myself), as an alternative to specifying variables with the `-V` flag, you can add them to the [YAML metadata block](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) of the markdown file. To change the fontsize, prepend following to your markdown document.

```
---
fontsize: 12pt
---
```

Works with fontsize 10,11, and 12. In addition to the comments on John MacFarlane's answer, there is some good info on specifying additional fontsizes with latex [in this article](http://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/) (inline latex can be used in pandoc markdown documents being converted to pdf).

Comment: i can't get this or any of the other solutions to work on `macOS` where I have `basicLatex` installed